# 2000 Server, User can't logon

Tags: exchange, server-message-block, windows-server-2000

I hope you can help me.  I recently upgraded a workstation at my office (to a whole new machine) and ran into a pretty serious problem.  Friday until 5:00 PM, I could access my mail on 2000 Exchange server.

When I shut the old workstation down and put in the new workstation, I tried to set up an account.  When I put the server name in appropriate field and typed my username and hit check names, my username does not come up.

So to troubleshoot, (It also is a SMB server)  I try to logon to my file share.  (My local credentials are the same as server credientials of user account)  When I try to logon to share, I just get the Username/Password screen (Never had gotten that before since credentials are the same)

Again, in troubleshooting mode, I try to log on to my user from another workstation.  Still can't authenticate via my user.  Every other user can authenticate and load up their shares/mailboxes.  I have restored Exchange from the backup as of 3 days ago (Thursday) but the exact same issue is still there.

I really do not understand what is wrong and what else I can do to troubleshoot.  If anyone has some pointers for me, I will surely accept them.

Thanks, Mike

EDIT:  Additional Info:  I copied my AD account and tried to login through that.  I can login ok to the newly created account but not the original.

Comment: You did a restore of the Exchange database to troubleshoot a single user access problem?  That's a new one...

Comment: We only have 6 users, the database is around 2GB

It is pretty important that work goes smoothly tomorrow and I didn't know what to do ( I am not a network admin at all )

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the computer to the AD computer list? You might need to add your workstation to the list of domain computers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked AD to make sure your account is still there?  Have you reset the password on the account?  It sounds like something is wrong with your account, and not the Exchange mailbox.

Comment: I have reset the password, changed account name.  These did not have an effect on the problem.  Is there a way to  just transfr the mailbox to another user?

Comment: @Mike, maybe the account is corrupt somehow?  If that is the case, since you can't log in to the old account to access the mail, it sounds like you'll have to use Exmerge to export the old mailbox to a .pst file and then import it to your new one.